# Unbalanced 4v4 Team Matchups?

Tags: starcraft-2

My friends and I play as a 4v4 team and are currently ranked 6 in bronze.   We are eager to break into silver, but have noticed that most of our matchups are against gold/platinum/diamond ranked players, and hence we get trampled.

How does the 4v4 team matchmaking work? Why is it that we are being matched up against players that are many leagues higher than us?  We play between 8.30-11.30pm in our area – is it just a coincidence that when we play there are no other silver-level 4v4 teams around?

Comment: Matchmaking works the same for all team sizes. If you are regularly matched against gold+ players, your matchmaking rating is likely higher than bronze, and the system is just trying to nail down your true "rating" before moving you.

Comment: Good point Wikiwocket. SC2Ranks.com puts us as ranked #71 in the region for Bronze (top 0.45%), so perhaps Blizzard is just testing us ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system is counting your skills over a very long period of time, it will try to keep your winning percentage to 50%.  So if you won a lot of games lately they are going to make you play against teams that are much more skilled than you are.  If you defeat the challenge several times they will make you advance league.  But if you are only able to win VS people that are in your skill frame I don't think you will ever be promoted.

Also take in consideration that when you play 4v4, you don't always against 4 friends, you can play against a team of 1 guy in diamond 2 in bronze and 1 in diamond by example.  From what I understand if you play with 4 friends they will consider you better than 4 random people in the same league as you.

8.30-11.30 pm is a pretty crowded period of time, so I don't think that has any influence, but there a much less people that play 4v4, so maybe that's why you think the match-up are not good if you only consider a short period of time.

Comment: Thanks Apoc. We generally can win against "Even" and "Slightly Favored" teams, and in fairness when we lose against "Favored" teams we only lose a small amount of points.

Answer (score -2):

A coordinated team of 1v1 Silver players can have a huge advantage over a team composed of 1v1 platinum/diamon players who just hit 4v4 -> Search.

Communication is pretty significant, use vent or something if you can. The most important is to coordinate armies. Share control, have everybody rush send a couple early units to a rally(Getting something like maybe 6 roaches, 6 stalkers, 2 zealots, 10 marines). Have whoever is best at keeping macro up while managing the army take control, while everybody else makes more units and workers, does a bit of tech. If the other players aren't coordinated, you'll get a lot of wins like this.

You can try out crazy but sometimes effective builds that only work in big team games, eg. Mass Phoenix/Raven, Medivacs+Zerg (They heal mutas and ultras!), or everybody sending gas to 1 player for really fast tech.

Have one person control your team's army, and be creative!

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Good suggestions, but doesn't really answer my question on matchmaking (which is probably why others have downgraded your answer).